# Place custom control between pan and zoom controls

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Any ideas how to place custom control **between** *pan* and *zoom* controls in google maps API v3?

I know how to do this when the custom control is **on the top** of native google's controls stack (for exmaple http://jsbin.com/ahetag). But it is not a solution...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `LEFT_TOP` control position for the "middle" element and then set it as a control option for the `zoomControl`.  So that the `panControl` is positioned as `TOP_LEFT` (by default) and then the other elements float downwards.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#ControlPosition