# Google maps custom control always appears below the default controls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to add a custom map control to a Google Maps v3 map.  My custom control is the grayed-out 'location' icon in the screenshot below.

[image: Current control positions]

The problem is that I need the custom control to be below the pan ('arrows') control, but *above* the pegman / street view control.  I have tried setting "index = -3" on the div I'm using for the control (see the [v3 custom control positioning docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomPositioning)), with no luck.

```
wrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
/* Some code appends an image to wrapperDiv in my actual code */
wrapperDiv.index = -3;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push( wrapperDiv );
```

Any ideas?

**Update - solution found**

Using the answer, provided by geocodezip, my custom control is now between the pan control and pegman control:

[image: Correct positions]

Most of the controls are now further over to the left than normal, but there doesn't seem to be a way to work around that, as far as I can tell.

**Follow-up question**

Now that my custom control is in the right place, is there a way to make the pegman and zoom controls centered below the pan control, like they are in the first screenshot?

Comment: I found that this relates to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9060683/132374

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One idea/option (not optimal but does sort of what you want).

1. Put the pan control in the TOP_LEFT controls position.
2. Put the custom control at index -1 (before all the normal controls) in LEFT_TOP

> from [the documentation: Positioning Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomPositioning):
> ...snip...
> The API places controls at each position by the order of an `index` property; controls with a lower index are placed first. For example, two custom controls at position `BOTTOM_RIGHT` will be laid out according to this index order, with lower index values taking precedence. By default, all custom controls are placed after placing any API default controls. ***You can override this behavior by setting a control's index property to be a negative value***. Custom controls cannot be placed to the left of the logo or to the right of the copyrights.

```
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: chicago,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    }
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(homeControlDiv);
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_control-customC.html)

- A second option, would be to create a custom zoom control, then you can control the order (I couldn't figure out how to access the pre-defined Google Maps controls, only to put the custom control(s) before or after them).

[example custom zoom/pan control](http://search.missouristate.edu/map/mobile/examples/ZoomPanControl.htm) from [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149305/googlemaps-api3-demogallery-example-custom-small-navigation-control)

```
  var PanControl = new geocodezip.web.PanControl(map);
  PanControl.index = -2;
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);
  homeControlDiv.index = -1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(PanControl);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(homeControlDiv);
```

[Example with a modified ZoomPanControl (just the pan control)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_control-custom_PanControl.html)

code snippet with code from above example:

```js
var map = null;
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

/**
 * The HomeControl adds a control to the map that simply
 * returns the user to Chicago. This constructor takes
 * the control DIV as an argument.
 * @constructor
 */
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
  // Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
  // from the edge of the map
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  // Set CSS for the control border
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Home</b>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to
  // Chicago
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago)
  });

}

function initialize() {
  // Create the DIV to hold the control and
  // call the HomeControl() constructor passing
  // in this DIV.
  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');


  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: chicago,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    }
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
  var PanControl = new geocodezip.web.PanControl(map);
  PanControl.index = -2;
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);
  homeControlDiv.index = -1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(PanControl);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(homeControlDiv);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

/**
 * @param {string} tagName
 * @param {Object.<string, string>} properties
 * @returns {Node}
 */
function CreateElement(tagName, properties) {
  var elem = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (var prop in properties) {
    if (prop == "style")
      elem.style.cssText = properties[prop];
    else if (prop == "class")
      elem.className = properties[prop];
    else
      elem.setAttribute(prop, properties[prop]);
  }
  return elem;
}

/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {google.maps.Map} map
 */
function PanControl(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originalCenter = map.getCenter();

  var t = this;
  var panContainer = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: relative; padding: 5px;"
  });

  //Pan Controls
  var PanContainer = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: relative; left: 2px; top: 5px; width: 56px; height: 56px; padding: 5px; overflow: hidden;"
  });
  panContainer.appendChild(PanContainer);
  var div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "width: 56px; height: 56px; overflow: hidden;"
  });
  div.appendChild(CreateElement("img", {
    'alt': ' ',
    'src': 'http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/mapcontrols3d5.png',
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -1px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 59px; height: 492px;"
  }));
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);

  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 19px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan left'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.LEFT);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 37px; top: 19px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan right'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.RIGHT);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 19px; top: 0px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan up'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.UP);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 19px; top: 37px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan down'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.DOWN);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 19px; top: 19px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Reset center'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.map.setCenter(t.originalCenter);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);

  return panContainer;
}

/** @param {PanDirection} direction */
PanControl.prototype.pan = function(direction) {
  var panDistance = 50;
  if (direction == PanDirection.UP || direction == PanDirection.DOWN) {
    panDistance = Math.round(this.map.getDiv().offsetHeight / 2);
    this.map.panBy(0, direction == PanDirection.DOWN ? panDistance : -1 * panDistance);
  } else {
    panDistance = Math.round(this.map.getDiv().offsetWidth / 2);
    this.map.panBy(direction == PanDirection.RIGHT ? panDistance : -1 * panDistance, 0);
  }
}

/** @enum */
var PanDirection = {
  LEFT: 0,
  RIGHT: 1,
  UP: 3,
  DOWN: 4
}

window["geocodezip"] = window["geocodezip"] || {};
window["geocodezip"]["web"] = window["geocodezip"]["web"] || {};
window["geocodezip"]["web"]["PanControl"] = PanControl;
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a doc about this negative index trick? I'm trying it to implement it on my application but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Added documentation reference to my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for placing controls before the default fullscreen control. any idea why it happens?

Comment: That is a different question.