# Controlling Google map position with custom button

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to change the location on Google map using custom controller instead of swiping on the mobile app or dragging on the browser?
I am looking for smooth changing position same as swipe/drag, and no jumping or shifting.
[image]

Comment: This question: [Google Maps Javascript positioning control maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769309/google-maps-javascript-positioning-control-maps) creates a custom pan control.  It doesn't _have_ to be on the map.

Answer (score 1):

One option, modified from the example in the question: [Google Maps Javascript positioning control maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769309/google-maps-javascript-positioning-control-maps):

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.300299, 34.471664),
    zoom: 6,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  });
  var PanControl = new geocodezip.web.PanControl(map);
  PanControl.index = 1;
  // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(PanControl);
  document.getElementById('panctrl').appendChild(PanControl);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

/**
 * @param {string} tagName
 * @param {Object.<string, string>} properties
 * @returns {Node}
 */
function CreateElement(tagName, properties) {
  var elem = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (var prop in properties) {
    if (prop == "style")
      elem.style.cssText = properties[prop];
    else if (prop == "class")
      elem.className = properties[prop];
    else
      elem.setAttribute(prop, properties[prop]);
  }
  return elem;
}

/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {google.maps.Map} map
 */
function PanControl(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originalCenter = map.getCenter();

  var t = this;
  var panContainer = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: relative; padding: 5px;"
  });

  //Pan Controls
  var PanContainer = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: relative; left: 2px; top: 5px; width: 56px; height: 56px; padding: 5px; overflow: hidden;"
  });
  panContainer.appendChild(PanContainer);
  var div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "width: 56px; height: 56px; overflow: hidden;"
  });
  div.appendChild(CreateElement("img", {
    'alt': ' ',
    'src': 'http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/mapcontrols3d5.png',
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -1px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 59px; height: 492px;"
  }));
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);

  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 19px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan left'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.LEFT);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 37px; top: 19px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan right'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.RIGHT);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 19px; top: 0px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan up'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.UP);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 19px; top: 37px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Pan down'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.pan(PanDirection.DOWN);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);
  div = CreateElement("div", {
    'style': "position: absolute; left: 19px; top: 19px; width: 18.6667px; height: 18.6667px; cursor: pointer;",
    'title': 'Reset center'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function() {
    t.map.setCenter(t.originalCenter);
  });
  PanContainer.appendChild(div);

  return panContainer;
}

/** @param {PanDirection} direction */
PanControl.prototype.pan = function(direction) {
  var panDistance = 50;
  if (direction == PanDirection.UP || direction == PanDirection.DOWN) {
    panDistance = Math.round(this.map.getDiv().offsetHeight / 2);
    this.map.panBy(0, direction == PanDirection.DOWN ? panDistance : -1 * panDistance);
  } else {
    panDistance = Math.round(this.map.getDiv().offsetWidth / 2);
    this.map.panBy(direction == PanDirection.RIGHT ? panDistance : -1 * panDistance, 0);
  }
}

/** @enum */
var PanDirection = {
  LEFT: 0,
  RIGHT: 1,
  UP: 3,
  DOWN: 4
}

window["geocodezip"] = window["geocodezip"] || {};
window["geocodezip"]["web"] = window["geocodezip"]["web"] || {};
window["geocodezip"]["web"]["PanControl"] = PanControl;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map_canvas {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float: right; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="panctrl" style="float: right;"></div>
```