# How to get zoom slider on google map v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3

I have tried almost all of the options on google map options, but I couldn't find one to enable the zoom level slider in the google map, It only shows the plus and minus button but not the zoom level slider.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Google has removed the old zoom slider from their UI that comes with google maps.

Comment: @Adam, Is there a way to add it?

Comment: Yeah, disable their zoom control (`{zoomControl:false}` in your `mapOptions`) and build your own using HTML/CSS/JavaScript. For what it's worth, it was removed in  September 2015 according to the release notes: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases

Comment: @Adam can you give me any reference for adding the slider?

Comment: Nope, I've never built one. You've got to come up with your own, or google around and see if somebody has built one that you can use. Keep in mind, your users are used to seeing google maps that **do not** have this zoom slider - why show them a familiar map interface with an unfamiliar home-made zoom control? Probably because your boss/the designer said so, eh? Just use the built-in one, your users will thank you.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the help, but google still shows that slider on their website, when you click on zoom plus or minus button, It asks you to show the zoom slider. and yes, It's the requirement from my client.

Comment: The map available on `maps.google.com` is **not** the map google sends out via it's Google Maps JavaScript API (not even close). Talk your client out of it, or make them pay extra if you have to take a few extra hours to build it yourself.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your help, I will build it myself :-)

Comment: Related question: [Google maps custom control always appears below the default controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266309/google-maps-custom-control-always-appears-below-the-default-controls)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?